# Attempting to get asteroids to move down screen themselves

Tags: c#, xna

I'm attempting to create an asteroids game and what I am trying to do is to get the asteroids to move down the screen themselves. The code I have loads the asteroids onto the screen however the asteroids do not move.

The code I have for the movement of the asteroids is listed below.

```
public class Asteroids
{
 public int speed;

public Asteroids(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
{
 speed = 2;
}
public LoadContent()
{
   while (asteroidsList.Count() < 5)
        {  
            randX = random.Next(0, 1000) + speed;
            randY = random.Next(-200, 984) + speed;
            asteroidsList.Add(new Asteroids(Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid big"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
        }
 }

public void Update (GameTime gameTime)
{
  // Update Origin
        if (texture != null)
        {
            Asteroidorigin.X = texture.Width / 2;
            Asteroidorigin.Y = texture.Height / 2;
        }
        foreach (Asteroids a in asteroidsList)
        {
            position.Y = position.Y + speed;
            position.X = position.X + speed;
        }
        if (position.X >= 1280)
            {
            position.X = -105;
            }
        if (position.Y >= 1024)
            {
            position.Y = -105;
            }
}
}

Game1.cs
namespace AsteroidsGame
{
// Main
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Random random = new Random();

    // List Of Asteroids
    

    // Making New Objects Of These Classes
    Player p = new Player();
    Background bg = new Background();
    Asteroids a = new Asteroids();
    EnemySpaceship es = new EnemySpaceship();

    // Constructor
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false; // Fullscreen mode
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280; // Screen Width
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1024; // Screen Height
        this.Window.Title = "12013951 Asteroids Game";
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }

    // Init
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    // Load Content
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        bg.LoadContent(Content);
        p.LoadContent(Content);
        a.LoadContent(Content);
        es.LoadContent(Content);
    }

    // Unload Content
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        
    }

    // Update
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

      
         bg.Update(gameTime);
        p.Update(gameTime);
        a.Update(gameTime);
        es.Update(gameTime);
        a.CheckCollisionAsteroid();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    // Draw
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        bg.Draw(spriteBatch); //Draws The Background
        p.Draw(spriteBatch); // Draws The Player
        a.Draw(spriteBatch); // Draws asteroids
        es.Draw(spriteBatch); // Draws enemy spaceships

        spriteBatch.End();
        

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    // Load Asteroids
 
}
}
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your foreach loop, I see you updating a position, but how is it related to each Asteroid a?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a.position inside the foreach loop, since position is a local variable belonging to each 'Asteroids' object?

Comment: tried doing this within the forach loop so that the foreach loop reads foreach (Asteroids a in asteroidsList) { a.position.X = a.position.X + speed} and i did the same with the y position but the asteroids still dont move

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the position of something, but I don't see how modifying that position property is modifying the position of each asteroid. You need each asteroid to have its own position property. You could try something like this (assuming `position` is a Vector2 property of the asteroid class):

```
public void Update (GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Asteroids a in asteroidsList)
    {
        a.position = new Vector2(
            MathHelper.Clamp(a.position.X + speed, -105, 1280),
            MathHelper.Clamp(a.position.Y + speed, -200, 1024));
    }
}
```

The `MathHelper.Clamp()` also removes the need for the `if` statements you have in the update method.

Comment: just added my game1.cs code, is the first part of the code supposed to go with the game1.cs file or within the code i put up first

Comment: Well, it was just an example on how you have to draw each asteroid with its position property. It was supposed to go in `Game1`, but you could easily modify it to go in the asteroid class. Basically, looking at your code, your problem is that each asteroid doesn't have its own position property.

Comment: when i try to implement the code above, instead of outputting 5 asteroids to the screen, its only outputting 1.

Comment: If your draw was working, go ahead an use that. However, try using the update code I wrote. This will assign each asteroid a position value, instead of making them all share the same one. (I had an error above; I fixed it)

Comment: not really, not your fault though, had to amend all my code and put the common code into a superclass

Comment: @user3158314 was the idea correct? Was the problem you weren't modify the position of each astroid? Just curious.